# Android Quiz Application where users create the quiz content by a web form

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, web-applications

I am developing an android quiz application for teachers where the teacher can login into a web interface and create questions, which can then be deployed to an android application.

My question is what database should i use? i am thinking that the data will have to be sorted on a mysql database when entered to the website.

Is it possible to connect to an external database on a android application? Is this the best method ?

Comment: you need to make web service calls to submit data to your server,which can then store in mysql

Comment: Thanks, Is mysql a good option in your opinion? i need to app to able to build the quiz from whats in the database i needs to a fast

Comment: I personally always use MySQL, but you can use whichever database is suited for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an external storage for your android application, you will need to create you own web service.

If you create an XML web service, you can then make calls to your service and parse the response with an `XmlPullParser`.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html for parsing XML.

Comment: forget xml and try to move on to JSON. Its fast, simple.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking a mix of JSON, php and mysql ?